# Open excel file for editing in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

I am working on asp.net mvc, my requirements are as follows

1. Upload any excel file(s)
2. Delete any excel file(s)
3. Edit any excel file

For this i followed a [tutorial](http://techbrij.com/crud-file-upload-asp-net-mvc-ef-multiple) and i am able to perform steps `1` and `2`. But for step `3` i am just able to edit only `Name` and `Description` as shown in the link

Now i want is that whenever i click `edit` the selected excel file should be opened and user can edit it and save it and the saved file whould be at the same location.

My `create` action code is bellow

```
  public ActionResult Create(Support support)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            List<FileDetail> fileDetails = new List<FileDetail>();
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];

                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    FileDetail fileDetail = new FileDetail()
                    {
                        FileName = fileName,
                        Extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName),
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid()
                    };
                    fileDetails.Add(fileDetail);

                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Upload/"), fileDetail.Id + fileDetail.Extension);
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                }
            }

            support.FileDetails = fileDetails;
            db.Supports.Add(support);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(support);
    }
```

Bellow is my razor for `create`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Support", null, FormMethod.Post,   new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
  {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Create Support Request</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Summary)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Summary)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Summary)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label>Files:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple" />
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Bellow is my action code for `edit`

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Support support)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            //New Files
            for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[i];

                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    FileDetail fileDetail = new FileDetail()
                    {
                        FileName = fileName,
                        Extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName),
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        SupportId = support.SupportId
                    };
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Upload/"), fileDetail.Id + fileDetail.Extension);
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                    db.Entry(fileDetail).State = EntityState.Added;
                }
            }

            db.Entry(support).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(support);
    }
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Support support = db.Supports.Include(s => s.FileDetails).SingleOrDefault(x => x.SupportId == id);
        if (support == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(support);
    }
```

Bellow is my razor syntax for edit

```
@model MultipleFileUpload.Models.Support
 @{
   ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
  }

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Support", null, FormMethod.Post, new    {    enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Edit Support Request</legend>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SupportId)
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Summary)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Summary)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Summary)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label>Files:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple" />
        <ul class="attachment">
            @foreach (var item in Model.FileDetails)
            {
                <li>
                    <a class="title" href="/Support/Download/?p=@(item.Id + item.Extension)&d=@item.FileName">@item.FileName</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="@item.Id" class="deleteItem">X</a>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
  }
  <div>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
  </div>
```

In edit razor i have a `delete` option, so bellow is my delete script

```
 @section Scripts 
     {
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
     <script>
            $('.deleteItem').click(function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
        var $ctrl = $(this);
        if (confirm('Do you really want to delete this file?')) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("DeleteFile")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { id: $(this).data('id') }
            }).done(function (data) {
                if (data.Result == "OK") {
                    $ctrl.closest('li').remove();
                }
                else if (data.Result.Message) {
                    alert(data.Result.Message);
                }
                 }).fail(function () {
                alert("There is something wrong. Please try again.");
              })
          }
      });
</script>
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Did you mean Name and **Summary** (you do not appear to have a `Description` property)

Comment: @StephenMuecke no no i just want to open the selected excel file to in edit

Comment: Did you read my comment (your question refers to a property named `Description` which does not exists - but one named `Summary` does so I assue you have a typo). And how do you expect your users to edit an excel file unless they download it, open Excel to edit it and then upload the file again. There are plugins such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) or [DevExpress](https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxSpreadsheetDemos/) that can give your some Excel functionality

Comment: @StephenMuecke, i did understand your question, and as you are saying that 'how do you expect your users to edit an excel file unless they download it, open Excel to edit it and then upload the file again', so does it means that one cannot edit excel file online ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke simple i want to open the uploaded excel file and then save it and saved file should be in same location

Comment: Have a look at the links in my previous comments